# How do I delete everything oath from my aspnetmvc project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget

How do I find out what references what with the DLLs from 3rd party (and MS)?

I have an AspnetMvc 4 project and see a DLLs named `*Oauth*` and `DotnetOpenAuth*`.
Now I'd like to get rid of unnecessary load and my project is anonymous so I thought it would be a good idea to delete said DLLs and references.

So I delete through Nuget

```
UnInstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth
```

But to no avail. I delete the files and update `packages.config` to realise *something needs them. But how do I find out what?* My stuff is not the culprit afaik.

Comment: In the default MVC4 project code, API from those DLLs is in use. So you need to Build the solution (after removing the DLLs) to check out where the code is breaking and go there and fix it. Especially places like AccountController.cs, AuthConfig.cs, InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs

Comment: @ramiramilu That is the easy part. Every reference in my code is removed; but the linker complains. I guess my code references a DLL that somewhere, although I don't need it, references an Oauth dll.

Comment: Interesting, Clean the solution in VS. I created MVC4 app, then I un-installed the DLL via nuget package manager. Then removed all references. Finally I was able to build the solution successfully and was able to run it. So there might be some unseen hookup in your code. Chec kfor that. Also do give a try by quickly creating a sample project and removing DLLS and building. If that works, then certainly there is some code which is referencing those DLLs.

Comment: I solved it by "Safe Delete" by Resharper. Let's hope it didn't mess something else up.

Comment: 3,5 months later site is still running so I guess "Safe Delete" mentioned above works.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can follow this tutorial step by step to create a webform ( same you can do in MVC ) also codes are available in GitHub. Here is the [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/19/building-a-basic-web-forms-application-using-visual-studio-2013.aspx?Redirected=true) :

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you pulled in the security portion of the mvc4 application. If you do not use the library(s) then you can discard them.

The main packages for MVC are

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor
Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
```

I don't think the above packages will pull in the oauth portions.